# htaccess filename.php?name=category to subdomain category.domain.com

Tags: php, .htaccess

Please help me:

What htaccess code a

```
filename.php?name=category to subdomain category.domain.com
```

thanks.
Sorry my english language is bad

Comment: Welcome to SO. Kindly have a [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to SO & come back again with your efforts & specific problem you face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Ali Arshad,

It's work with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^\.w{3}]+\.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^$ %{HTTP_HOST} [C]
RewriteRule ^([^\.w{3}]+)\.domain\.com$ filename.php?name=$1
```

I am very grateful, because it has helped me find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following htaccess should do the job:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=(.*)$
RewriteRule filename.php http://%1.domain.com [R=301,L]
```